# C - unaddressable byte for dynamic memory string

Tags: c, compiler-errors, malloc, heap-memory, valgrind

I have this context :

```
char* bname(char const *mypath) {    //basename
    char* bnm = (char*) malloc((strlen(mypath)+1)*sizeof(char));
    char lim='/';
    char* z = strrchr(mypath, lim);
    if (z) {
        strcpy(bnm, z + 1);
    } else {
        strcpy(bnm,mypath);
    }
    return bnm;
}

void doX(int sockfd, char* filename) {
    if (send(sockfd, filename, 1024, 0) == -1) {
        // exit;
    }

    /*
    No error with this one:
    if (send(sockfd, "test", 1024, 0) == -1) {
        // exit
    }
    */
}
```

Which is called exclusively in main like that :

```
// argv[3] = test.jpg
char* fname= bname(argv[3]);
doX(socketd, fname);
free(fname);
```

Compilation : gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -ggdb3

Valgrind : valgrind --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck

```
Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==7096==    at 0x4F5EC4D: send (send.c:28)
==7096==    by 0x109197: doX (client.c:94)
==7096==    by 0x1093A0: main (client.c:146)
==7096==  Address 0x522e2f9 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==7096==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7096==    by 0x108F38: bname (client.c:43)
==7096==    by 0x109378: main (client.c:145)
```

I can't seem to find the reason of this warning, it most probably is the send() of doX since if I give it a literal string no warning appears.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `send(sockfd, filename, 1024, 0)`: I believe, `filename` doesn't provide 1024 bytes. Hence, you access out of bound and valgrind doesn't like this.

Comment: Btw. `send(sockfd, "test", 1024, 0)` is wrong as well. _No error with this one_ is just bad luck. (or luckily bad?)

Comment: I think send() wants a 'const void *', not a 'char *'.

Comment: @GermanNerd I don't think that's an issue. If it were it would be a compile time issue - not a runtime issue in valgrind...

Comment: @GermanNerd the C standard guarantee that `void *` can be converted to and back from any object, for this exact reason `send()` use it. The problem is that outlined by @Scheff. The correct syntax should be `send(sockfd, filename, strlen(filename), 0)`

Comment: @Frankie_C Thank you. So send and recv buff size are unrelated? Am i allowed to put 1024 in recv? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: _Am i allowed to put 1024 in recv?_ Yes, if (and only if) you provide a buffer with at least 1024 bytes. (Otherwise, valgrind is back in game.) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

change it like

```
if (send(sockfd, filename, strlen(filename)+1, 0) == -1) {
```

filename may don't have that much memory (1024 bytes) allocated